# join the SAS datases sideways, horizontal

Tags: sql, join, merge, sas

I have a dataset as following

```
ID  A1  A2  A3
A   1.2 1.5 1
A   1.3 1.7 1.3
A   1.4 1.8 1.7
B   1.5 1.8 1.9
B  1.6 1.7 1.0
```

and result I am looking for is

```
A   1.2 1.5 1 1.3 1.7 1.3 1.4 1.8 1.7
```

I know that SAS variable names cannot be repeated but when I tried Proc SQL, with inner join it gives me more rows.

Comment: Do you know in advance what the maximum number of rows per ID will be?  Also, this will be very hard to do using SQL unless you also have another variable in your dataset that starts from 1 at the first row for each ID and increments by 1 for each consecutive row with the same ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SAS datastep is the best option here.  Set up an array to read each value in turn, including across rows, storing them in a new array, then only output after the last ID is read.

The only problem is that you need to know the maximum number of values an ID can take, which will be nrows x ncols (not just the number of rows).  In your example the anser is 9, as ID A has 3 rows and 3 columns.  One solution is to set the number of elements in the new array to be higher than you think you'll need, it just means there will be some empty columns at the end of your dataset.  I've set the value to be 10 in my code below.

```
data have;
input ID $  A1  A2  A3;
datalines;
A   1.2 1.5 1
A   1.3 1.7 1.3
A   1.4 1.8 1.7
B   1.5 1.8 1.9
B  1.6 1.7 1.0
;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id;
retain newA1-newA10; /* keep values across rows */
array oldvars{*} A: ; /* array of existing variables */
array newvars{*} newA1-newA10; /* array of new variables */
if first.id then do; /* reset counter and array values when ID changes */
    counter=0;
    call missing(of newA1-newA10);
    end;
do i = 1 to dim(oldvars); /* loop through each value and store in new array */
    counter+1;
    newvars{counter} = oldvars{i};
end;
if last.id then output; /* only output after last ID is read */
drop A: counter i; /* drop unwanted variables */
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Longfish's but as DOW.  However, in DOW processing you do not need to retain the array items because the wide array is populated within a single iteration of the implicit DATA Step loop.

```
* measure the data;
data _null_;
  set have end=last_row;
  by ID;
  array A A1-A3;
  retain max_group_size 0;
  if first.ID then group_size = 0;
  group_size + 1; * implicit retain;
  if last.ID then max_group_size = max (max_group_size, group_size);
  if last_row then do;
    call symputx ('wide_count', max_group_size * dim(A));
  end;
run;

* extrude the data;
data want(keep=ID AX:);
  do _wide_index = 0 by 0 until (last.id);  /* initialize wide_index and loop over group */
    set have;
    by ID;

    array A A1-A3;
    array AX AX1-AX&wide_count; * X is for eXtruded :) ;

    do _small_index = 1 to dim (A);
      _wide_index + 1;
      AX [ _wide_index ] = A [ _small_index ];
    end;
  end;
  * implicit output occurs here because there is no explicit output statement elsewhere in the step;
run;
```